# How do I prevent the closing of modal popup window(ModalPopupExtender) on postback?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Microsoft AjaxControlToolkit for modal popup window.

And on a modal popup window, when a postback occurred, the window was closing. How do I prevent from the closing action of the modal popup?

Comment: Ali hocam, Bunun bi çaresini bulabildin mi. Ben de aynı dertten muzdaribim.

Answer (score 12):

Put you controls inside the update panel. Please see my sample code, pnlControls is control that holds controls that will be displayed on popup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlControls" runat="server">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID="TestButton" runat="server" Text="Test Button" onclick="TestButton_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>         
        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This will do the job for you :)

Best regards,
Gregor Primar

Comment: This works well. You can actually wrap the entire set of controls in the modal if needed to help prevent having to create a bunch more UpdatePanels all with triggers to the other UpdatePanels.

Comment: I had hope this would of work but this didn't fix my issue for the modal is still showed and then closed ... Does anyone know why it is closed after it is shown? I want that users click on a button, modal shows and stays open till closed by user.  Also for those trying the same, you need to add the ScriptManager tag before your panel, and only 1 such tag is allowed per page so put it in your master page ;) .

Answer (score 10):

You can call `Show()` method during postback to prevent the modal popup window from closing

```
MyModalPopoupExtender.Show()
```

Comment: This worked for me, and removed the need for UpdatePanels which seem to do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // reshow
        MyModalPopup.Show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Was having this same problem keeping a modal open during postbacks.

My solution:

Use EventTarget to determine if the postback is coming from a control in the modal and keep the model open if it is.   The postback can come from a control in the modal iff the modal is open.

In the load event for the page control containing the modal.  Determine if the postback is from
a child of mine.  Determine if it is from the control that is in the modal panel.

```
    Protected Sub Control_Load(sende As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If IsPostBack Then
            Dim eventTarget As String = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EventTarget")
            Dim eventArgs As String = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EventArgument")

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(eventTarget) AndAlso eventTarget.StartsWith(Me.UniqueID) Then
                If eventTarget.Contains("$" + _credentialBuilder.ID + "$") Then
                    ' Postback from credential builder modal.  Keep it open.
                    showCredentialBuilder = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

In prerender check my flag and manually show the modal

```
    Protected Sub Control_PreRender(ByVal sende As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        If showCredentialBuilder Then
            _mpeCredentialEditor.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that works but not in my case. I've a user control that opened in a modal popup and this user control makes postback itself. So in that user control I've no modal popup property.

I guess, I've to create an event for my user control, and the page that opens the modal popup have to reopen it in this event.

Answer (score 1):

Like you prolly already know, the modal popup is clientside only, yeah you can gather informations in it during the postback, but if you do a postback he will hide 100% of the time.

Of course, like other proposed, you can do a .show during the postback, but it depends on what you need to do.

Actually, I don't know why you need a postback, if it's for some validations try to do them clientside.

Could you tell us why you need to do a postback, maybe we could help you better ! :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but I really don't remember the problem :) I guess we got rid of it.

Comment: hahaha !!! ok then XD
Maybe you could post your solution (the way it's working atm) if you don't mind. I'm pretty curious about the case and I would like to see how you can do it!

Comment: For me, I need my button to run server-side code in my code behind. Is there a way to do that without a postback?