# Avoid modal popup window closing on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

How to avoid modal popup closing on postback ?.. I have a popup window displaying a grid view after a buttonclick event. but the pop up closes after the button is clicked ?? Can anyone help ??

Comment: You need to give us some code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Some relevant snippets would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this question it may help you, just recall the modalpop.show() again.

[How do I prevent the closing of modal popup window(ModalPopupExtender) on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824/how-do-i-prevent-the-closing-of-modal-popup-windowmodalpopupextender-on-postba)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you will need to preserve the modal popup state in order to reinitiate it again after the postback.

What I can suggest is to setup a hiddenfield control that only holds the state of your modal *(0-1, true-false, whatever you like)*, and with Javascript, it's easy to change the hiddenfield value in order to reflect the current popup state.

When the page get posted back and reloads again, setup an onload javascript function that  checks for the hiddenfield's value, and then react based on it to show the popup again as soon as the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an asynchronous postback or set a flag and show the dialog again after the postback.