# Add Form in a Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal-dialog

I making an add form in my modal. The modal contains 2 dropdownlists, 4 textboxes (1 hidden) and a button for adding.

I bind my dropdown list for the item category then bind my other dropdown list for the item name. However when I change my Item Category in my dropdown list the dropdown list for my item name is not responding or it not binding. Can anyone help me?

```html
<div id="addModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Item</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-inline form-group">
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="control-label col-xs-3" runat="server" Text="Category:"></asp:Label>
          <div class="col-xs-offset-3">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpCategory" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-xs-5" OnTextChanged="drpCategory_TextChanged" />
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-inline form-group">
          <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="control-label col-xs-3" runat="server" Text="Item Name:"></asp:Label>
          <div class="col-xs-offset-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtitem" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-xs-5" Visible="false" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpItem" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-xs-5" Visible="true" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline form-group">
          <asp:Label ID="Label3" CssClass="control-label col-xs-3" runat="server" Text="Unit:"></asp:Label>
          <div class="col-xs-offset-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnit" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-xs-5" Enabled="false" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline form-group">
          <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="control-label col-xs-3" runat="server" Text="Quantity:"></asp:Label>
          <div class="col-xs-offset-3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-xs-3" type="number" min="1" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnADD" CssClass="btn btn-sm" OnClick="btnADD_Click" Text="Add" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

then  this is the code behind:

```
public void drpCategory_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (drpCategory.Text == "Others")
    {
        drpItem.Visible = false;
        txtitem.Visible = true;
    } 
    else
    {
        byCateg();
        DataBind();
        drpItem.Visible = true;
        txtitem.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Is there a problem in my code?

Comment: did you set the autopostback to true?

Comment: not yet sir where should i set the autopostback?

Comment: ganun ba? try mo sa properties, or directly add AutoPostBack="True"

Comment: kaninung properties kay modal???

Comment: sa dropdown, specific control po (e.g. `drpCategory`)

Comment: nag coclose naman po ung modal pag nag AutoPostBack po ako

Comment: :P ganun talaga, dapat mag postback, pag modal , try mo search `ajax control toolkit`, `modal popup extender` na control

Comment: try mo din enclose ng updatepanel

Comment: kc dapat po ndi po sya nag coclose dapat nag uupdate lang ung isa pang dropdown list ee...

Comment: check mo 2 baka makatulong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824/how-do-i-prevent-the-closing-of-modal-popup-windowmodalpopupextender-on-postba

Comment: may nakita po akong update panel dun ittry ko po sya salamat po

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir :3
gumamit ako ng Update Panel for this tnx panu ko ba ma uup ung repo mo sir

Comment: hahha pwd lang add mo as answer tapos i upvote mo :P

Comment: hanap nalang ako sa mga post mo upvote ko nalang sir salamat ulit